# How i can optimize this animation? Canvas. Javascript. Cursor animation

Tags: javascript

This animation (based on [the answer](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1344910/312975) of 
[Вася Воронцов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/312975/%d0%92%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%92%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%be%d0%b2)) loads the computer very much. I do this animation in canvas. Animation loads proccesor very much. Here the light follows the cursor and leaves traces. Animation works correctly but proccesor loads very much.

Deleting and changing the radii of circles is done by saving their coordinates.

The effect is controlled by changing the variables radius (circle radius), period (time for which the circle disappears), color (circle color), blur (blur radius) and cursor radius (pointer circle radius).

How to optimize this animation so that it loads the computer less?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = document.body.offsetWidth;
var height = document.body.offsetHeight;
var points = [], 
    cursor = [-10, -10];
var t = 0;

var radius = 100;
var period = 2100;
var color = "rgba(239, 91, 59, .5)";
var blur = 600;

canvas.style.width = canvas.width = width;
canvas.style.height = canvas.height = height;
context.fillStyle = color;
var filter = context.filter = "blur(" + 50 + "px)";
var dr = radius / period;

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  let i = 0;
  let deleted = 0;
  let dt = -t + (t = window.performance.now());
  context.beginPath();
  while (i++ < points.length-1) {
    let p = points[i];
    p[2] += dt;
    let r = radius - p[2] * dr;
    context.moveTo(p[0], p[1]);
    if (p[2] <= period) {
      context.arc(p[0], p[1], r, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
    } else deleted = i;
  }
  context.fill();
  points.splice(0, deleted);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(cursor[0], cursor[1], 20, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
  context.filter = "none";
  context.fill();
  context.filter = filter;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

window.onmousemove = function(event) {
  let x = event.pageX;
  let y = event.pageY;
  let backwardX = 0;
  let backwardY = 0;

  backwardX += (x-backwardX) / 5
  backwardY += (y-backwardY) / 5


  points.push([x, y, 0]);
  cursor = [x, y];
}

t = window.performance.now();
window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

PS: [Question in Russian.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1353113/178988)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's slow because you have a lot of overdraw. Each frame, a large number of points is being drawn, and each point touches a lot of pixels.

You can achieve something that looks very similar if you realize that the canvas retains its contents between frames. So every frame, you could do something like this:

1. Fade the canvas towards white by drawing a nearly transparent white rectangle over it.
2. Draw *one* new blurred point, at the current cursor location.

The circle that follows the mouse can easily be achieved by overlaying a separate element on top of the canvas, for example a `<div>`. Use `transform: translate(x, y);` to move it, which is more performant than using `left`/`top` because it's a [compositor-only property](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count). Add `will-change: transform;` for an extra potential performance boost.